# Simple pulley free body diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to create the following image in tikz.

[image]

I am completely new to it, so I tried to change the code at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/free-body-diagrams/

to

```
\def\iangle{90} 

\def\down{-90}
\def\arcr{0.5cm} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    force/.style={>=latex,draw=blue,fill=blue},
    axis/.style={densely dashed,gray,font=\small},
    M/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=lightgray,minimum size=0.5cm,thin},
    m/.style={rectangle,draw=black,fill=lightgray,minimum size=0.3cm,thin},
    plane/.style={draw=black,fill=blue!10},
    string/.style={draw=red, thick},
    pulley/.style={thick},
]

\matrix[column sep=1cm] {
   \draw[plane] (0,-1) coordinate (base)
                     -- coordinate[pos=0.5] (mid) ++(\iangle:3) coordinate (top)
                     |- (base) -- cycle;
    \path (mid) node[M,rotate=\iangle,yshift=0.5cm] (M) {};
&
    %%%
    % Free body diagram of M2 pulley
    \draw[pulley] (top) -- ++(\iangle:0.25) circle (0.5cm)
                   ++ (90-\iangle:0.5) coordinate (pulley);
    \draw[string] (M.east) -- ++(\iangle:2.0cm) arc (90+\iangle:0:0.25)
                  -- ++(0,-1) node[m] {};
\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but I am not close. Some basic pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: A matrix is used to align an array of nodes.  You definitely don't want `\draw`s inside.  (base), (mid) and (top) are undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex]
   \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (10mm);
   \draw[thick,->](-1,0)--++(0,-2)node[below]{$T_2$};
   \draw[thick,->](1,0)--++(0,-2)node[below]{$T_2$};
   \draw[thick,->](0,0)--++(0,2)node[above]{$T_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}` and `>=Latex` are to give the latex arrow heads in the OP.